# LLVM : 'First Function' tutorial not working for me

Tags: llvm

I am working on a Ubuntu 13.10 64bit OS.
I've downloaded and built LLVM 3.4 with make.
Compiler: gcc 4.8.1
Shell: zsh

In the process of configuring it, a used the default prefix `/usr/local/`. I did not use any other custom options.

The source code and the build is in my home folder:

```
~/llvm_workdir/build
~/llvm_workdir/llvm
```

When I tried the [First Function tutorial](http://llvm.org/releases/2.4/docs/tutorial/JITTutorial1.html) I faced a bunch of problems. The first problems had to do with the fact that they have made some changes in the source tree. They moved some header files (e.g. Function.h) in the IR directory. (The tutorial is for the 2.4 version of llvm.) I corrected the includes in the tutorial source code file and new errors came to life. The first category is something like these:

```
1]
zsh: command not found: llvm-config : I'm using the `zsh shell`, which is compatible with bash.

2]
In file included from /usr/include/llvm/Support/type_traits.h:20:0,
from /usr/include/llvm/ADT/StringRef.h:13,
from /usr/include/llvm/PassRegistry.h:20,
from /usr/include/llvm/PassSupport.h:26,
from /usr/include/llvm/Pass.h:366,
from /usr/include/llvm/PassManager.h:20,
from tut1_first_function.cpp:6:
/usr/include/llvm/Support/DataTypes.h:49:3: **error: #error "Must #define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS before #including Support/DataTypes.h"
# error "Must #define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS before #including Support/DataTypes.h"**
^
/usr/include/llvm/Support/DataTypes.h:53:3: error: #error "Must #define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS before " "#including Support/DataTypes.h"
 # error "Must #define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS before " \

3]
In file included from /usr/include/llvm/ADT/SmallVector.h:19:0,
from /usr/include/llvm/PassAnalysisSupport.h:22,
from /usr/include/llvm/Pass.h:367,
from /usr/include/llvm/PassManager.h:20,
from tut1_first_function.cpp:6:
/usr/include/llvm/Support/MathExtras.h: In function ‘bool llvm::isInt(int64_t)’:
/usr/include/llvm/Support/MathExtras.h:259:33: **error: there are no arguments to ‘INT64_C’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘INT64_C’ must be available [-fpermissive]
return N >= 64 || (-(INT64_C(1)<<(N-1)) <= x && x < (INT64_C(1)<<(N-1)));**
```

The second category has to do with the change of signatures in some methods internally:

```
tut1_first_function.cpp:44:26: note: candidate is:
In file included from /usr/include/llvm/IR/GlobalValue.h:22:0,
from /usr/include/llvm/IR/Function.h:25,
from /usr/include/llvm/IR/Module.h:19,
from tut1_first_function.cpp:7:
/usr/include/llvm/IR/DerivedTypes.h:58:23: note: static llvm::IntegerType* **llvm::IntegerType::get(llvm::LLVMContext&, unsigned int)
static IntegerType *get(LLVMContext &C, unsigned NumBits);
                       ^
/usr/include/llvm/IR/DerivedTypes.h:58:23: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided**
```

I do not know what other parameter to pass in get. I'm new in LLVM, I'm starting learning it now. I haven't found any new tutorials that correspond to the new LLVM version.

How can I solve the above problems? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

LLVM is under active development. An attempt to apply a tutorial written to version 2.4 - which is over 5 years old - to an up-to-date version will be a lesson in frustration.

[The Kaleidoscope tutorial](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/index.html) is up-to-date and usually maintained as such with new versions, so I recommend using it instead. In particular, [lesson 3](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl3.html) looks like it covers the topics in the page you linked.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it and I'll come to accept your answer. :)

Comment: This doesn't look like the first function tutorial: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/llvm/examples/Kaleidoscope/Chapter3/toy.cpp